# What compact central objects younger than the crab pulsar have been seen?

Tags: astronomy, black-holes, neutron-stars

We see the crab pulsar, we don't see any compact remnant from Supernova 1987A.
I can't find any others, but I believe they exist.  Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Crab is one of the youngest [SNR's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_remnant) we know of in the galaxy, so I wouldn't have expected to find one younger, but I did. I present to you [SNR 0540](http://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2004/snr0540/), as observed by Chandra X-ray observatory:

[image]

Unfortunately, this is really the best we can do because it's 160,000 light-years away! (For reference, Crab is about 6000 light-years away). This remnant is estimated to be about 750 years old, so it's about 250 years younger than Crab.

In the general case, there are other SNRs that have compact objects located in the vicinity. First up is [IC 443](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IC_443):
[image]

[source (with description)](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap060602.html)

and [Puppis A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppis_A):

[image]

[source (also with description)](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap961114.html)